# How to remove meta title and description in WP_head() function in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, seo, metadata

Am using rankmath plugin in Phlox theme. In View page source show 2 meta title and description. I want to remove default meta data from theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an Answer. Usually, some themes support SEO, So if we use Rankmath or Yoast SEO we need to off Theme SEO Option. After turn off, It's Sorted.